# Getting week number from a date format

Tags: r

My dataframe has a date vector which in the format of :2/14/2003, 11/30/2007, 10/18/2002.

Doing a print command gives me numbers:

```
> print (c(movieDB$releaseDate[1:5]))
[1] 461 304 130 495 858
```

How do I extract week numbers from this data?

Thanks
Sinha

Answer (score 1):

Put your dates into date format and then use the `lubridate` package:

```
library(lubridate)
d <- as.Date("11/30/2007", format="%m/%d/%Y")
d
week(d)

#48
```

Comment: Thank you - The formatting was what I was doing wrong